# A git conflict was detected in package-lock.json after changing branches

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

[image]

after I switched to another branch of my coworker, I got this warning after I run `npm install` .

After a while it gave me these warnings and error at the end;

[image]

I can't solve this for hours. What can I do ?

Comment: Did you try deleting the package-lock.json and generating it again?